# Read a file into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Say I have a simple file like so holding arbitrary values:

```
A, 20, Monday, 14, Tuesday, 15, Tuesday, 16
B, 40, Wednesday, 14, Friday, 12
```

How would I get it into a nested dictionary so that each k/v pair looks like:

```
{'A': {'A':'20', 'Monday': '14', 'Tuesday': ['15', '16']},
'B': {'B':'40', 'Wednesday': '14', 'Friday': '12'}}
```

(If a key error arises from having 'A' and 'B' appear as keys twice, it doesn't matter if the second occurrence of each is replaced with something else.)

My knowledge of nested dictionaries isn't great, so the furthest I've been able to get is reading the lines into a list and having the whole list stored as a value with the key being the first line element.

```
d = {}
with open (filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        line = line.strip('\r').strip('\n').split(',')
        d[line[0]] = line
```

which returns the output

```
{'A': ['A', '20', 'Monday', '14', 'Tuesday', '15', 'Tuesday', '16'], 'B': 
['B', '40', 'Wednesday', '14', 'Friday', '12']}
```

Comment: @user7222454 The correct form should look like this: 

`{'A': {'A':'20'}, {'Monday': '14'}, {'Tuesday': ['15', '16']},
'B': {'B':'40'}, {'Wednesday': '14'}, {'Friday': '12'}}`

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my original question; how would I get the file to be read into the dict in this format then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
with open(filename) as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

output = {}

for s in lines: 
    split_line = s.split(",")
    first = split_line[0].strip()
    output[first] = {}
    output[first][first] = split_line[1].strip()
    pairs = []
    for i in range(0, len(split_line[2:]), 2):
        pairs.append(split_line[2:][i:i+2])

    for pair in pairs:
        day = pair[0].strip()
        output[first].setdefault(day, []).append(pair[1].strip())

    print output
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'A': {'A': '20', 'Tuesday': ['15', '16'], 'Monday': ['14']}, 'B': {'B': '40', 'Friday': ['12'], 'Wednesday': ['14']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `{'Tuesday': '15', '16'}`

This does not seem valid so I'm going to assume you want `{'Tuesday': ['15', '16']}`

For each of the lists you'll have to do this:

```
newdict = {}
key = None
for item in list:
    if key is None:
        key = item
    else:
        if key not in newdict:
            newdict[key] = []
        newdict[key].append(item)
        key = None
```

I tested this on one of your lists and it worked.

*Edit*
Output looks like this:

```
{'A': ['20'], 'Tuesday': ['15', '16'], 'Monday': ['14']}
```