# Converting lines of a file containing arrays to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a file, each line of which contains data that I would like to read into a dictionary, resulting in a list of dictionaries. Or a dictionary of dictionaries, keyed by the first element from each line. The first element of each line is the only one that I can guarantee will be of the same type from line to line, i.e. it's a name. 
The data in the file looks something like this:

```
name:value1, var2:('str1', 'str2','str3'), var3:[0.1,1,10] , var4:range(1,10)
name:value2, var5:('str1', 'str2'), var6:range(1,10)
```

And I'd like to have it end up something like this:

```
dictionaryList=[
{"name": "value1", "var2":('str1', 'str2','str3'), var3:[0.1,1,10] , var4:range(1,10)},
{name:value2, var5:('str1', 'str2'), var6:range(1,10)}
]
```

There's a number of questions about reading lines into elements of a single dictionary or [reading a file into a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662449/read-a-file-into-a-nested-dictionary). They all rely on splitting the line on a comma though. i.e.

```
content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        line = line.strip('\r').strip('\n').split(':')
```

If I do that, I end up with breaks in the ranges and arrays and wotnot. I was borderline going to use : as a separator, but that feels like horribly bad form and I have no way to automatically convert the correct commas to colons when I get sent more data. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: 1. Break on colons, you will get a list.
2. Break each element in list on `,` and consider last element of this list as key and first element is value to previous key. 
Sounds reasonable?

Comment: That would still break ('str1','str2','str3'), var3 into 4 parts would it not?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know the actual format of the file. By format, i meant that the spaces after the commas. cause if the value of the attributes had commas but didn't have space before or after them but then the commas which signified the split between the attributes had spaces after them, then you could use this to your advantage. :)

Comment: I don't have much in the way of control over the data before it gets to me. I can get rid of spaces easy enough. I wouldn't want to count on them being all in the right place every time though.

Comment: @Ben but you can join them again and use

Comment: your keys and values are a string then, randomly (?), a variable. how do you know which is which? examples: `"name"` in first dict, `name` in second. `"var2"` and `var3` or `"value1"` and `value2`

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
dictList = []
stack = []
brack = "([{"
opbrack = ")]}"
for line in lines:
    d = {}
    key = ""
    val = ""
    k = 0
    for i in line:
        if i == ',':
            if not(stack) or stack[-1] not in brack:
                d[key] = val
                key = ""
                val = ""
                k = 0
            elif k==0:
                key += i
            else:
                val += i
        elif i in brack:
            stack.append(i)
            if k==0:
                key += i
            else:
            val += i
        elif i in opbrack:
            stack.pop()
            if k==0:
                key += i
            else:
                val += i
        elif i == ":":
             if not(stack) or stack[-1] not in brack:
                k = 1
            elif k==0:
                key += i
            else:
                val += i
        else:
            if k==0:
                key += i
            else:
                val += i
    dictList.append(d)
print dictList
```

This code should do what you need. It assumes that the file is already in proper format.

This is the output:

```
[{'name': 'value1', ' var2': "('str1', 'str2','str3')", ' var3': '[0.1,1,10] '}, {' var5': "('str1', 'str2')", 'name': 'value2'}]
```